# How to securely implement a deadpool in a PoW blockchain?

Tags: security, cryptography, rsa, blockchain, cryptocurrency

Imagine you have a blockchain where the Proof of Work scheme is integer factorization. There is an opcode that takes two integers N,M where it returns true if M∉{0,1,N} and N mod M ≡ 0. Now, suppose we want a number factored, say Mg. It could be a Cunningham number, a brilliant number or any other number where there is an interest in knowing its factorization.

We can create a transaction where the locking script for the funds of the transaction is this opcode with Mg as the first input. This way the unlocking script is just any non-trivial factor of Mg. This would allow anyone on the blockchain to claim the reward for this factorization.

Two issues: miner-in-the-middle attack and reorganization attack.

**Miner-in-the-Middle Attack:** The miner who receives a transaction with the unlocking script will be able to see the factor in plain sight and replace that transaction with one where the funds are sent to their wallets instead of the solver's.

**Reorganization Attack:** If the value of the blockchain's coin is high there is also an incentive to attack the block in which a solver transaction was mined by re-solving that block with a replaced transaction accrediting themselves(the attacker) and attempting to create a longer chain from this new block.

So,the question becomes, how can solutions be submitted safely in this blockchain? Is it possible to do it in two transactions, or are three transactions required? Is there any blockchain that has solved this problem already?

Thank you.

**Note 1:** I choose tags that are the most related to this topic. It also seems like the bitcoin stack exchange is strictly for bitcoin.

**Note 2:** This question was posted on the cryptography stack exchange to get ideas on cryptographic mechanisms that might help implement this. It is also posted here because there is a blockchain tag and there may be implementation details and solutions which may be achieved with the current opcode set plus this new opcode. It seems this community stack exchange is the most suited for the latter.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't a programming question, it's a crypto question.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, did you see the crypto tag? Also, I am asking for a software engineering solution if there is one.